# Does a comma have to be used before 'because'?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> I have a big house because my parents are rich.
>   I have a big house, because my parents are rich.

Are there are some exceptions as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, a comma isn't needed, but there are cases where the comma is needed. One such incident is taken from the [Chicago Manual of Style:](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/CMS_FAQ/Commas/Commas19.html)

> He didn’t run, because he was afraid.
>
> He didn’t run because he was afraid.

The author explained that, without the comma, as in the second sentence, It could mean two things:

He didn't run, for the reason that he was afraid
or
He ran, but not for the reason of being afraid.

In this case, it would be helpful to have a comma to clarify matters.

Otherwise, a comma before 'because' is usually not needed.

Comment: Better would be to swap order along with keeping the comma: "Because he was afraid, he didn’t run."